# Qt subclassing a ui form shows a blank window

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I have a qt .ui form and I am trying to use the subclassing approach described on their website to use it in a program. However, when I run the program, i just get an empty window.

subclass header:

```
#ifndef HOMEPAGE_H
#define HOMEPAGE_H
#include "ui_homepage.h"

class HomePage : public QWidget, public Ui::HomePage
{
public:
    HomePage(QMainWindow* window);
};

#endif // HOMEPAGE_H
```

subclass cpp file:

```
#include "homepage.h"

HomePage::HomePage(QMainWindow* window)
{
    setupUi(window);
}
```

program file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "homepage.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    HomePage homepage(window);
    homepage.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you add a link to that "approach described on the website"?

Comment: I assume it is [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-multipleinheritance-example.html) and your question has nothing to do with QML. I edited the tags accordingly. If you insist on the QML-tag you should start over and read about QML first.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this:

```
HomePage::HomePage(QMainWindow* window) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}
```

You're calling `setupUi` on the parent.

I would add the Q_OBJECT macro as well, if you're about to use signals and slots.

```
class HomePage : public QWidget, public Ui::HomePage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HomePage(QMainWindow* window);
};
```

Also, I would call `show` on both `HomePage` and `QMainWindow`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    HomePage homepage(window);
    homepage.show();
    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```